# Possible for ActionScript 3 to play user's local video files in a web browser?

Tags: actionscript-3

Or only possible to play it loading over the internet?

Comment: of course! i mean user selects a video file on his computer and the app plays it. that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Start with [FileReference.browse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse%28%29), when user selected file, you can play it with [FLVPlayback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#includeExamplesSummary) (Flash) or mx:Video (Flex). Your project must be not network enabled (flash can't access both network and local files).

P.S. and don't confuse comments with answers.